# Assign A Category To An Image In Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, categories

I thought my question would have a fairly simple answer, but my research has proven otherwise. What I would like to know is if there is a way that I can assign a category to an image in my library on my Wordpress site? To be even more specific, I am not referring to applying a thumbnail image to a category page, or post of a certain category. I have a category named "slider", and I want to be able to apply that category to images in my library. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

- [Media Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/screenshots/)

  > Provides ability to tag media/attachments via Media Management screens
- [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-categories-2/screenshots/)

  > Easily assign categories to media with a clean, simple, and searchable category meta box. Then use the gallery shortcode to display category galleries
- [Media Category Library](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-category-library/screenshots/)

  > WordPress plugin that allows items in the Media Library to be assigned to a category.

Related Q&A's at WPSE:

- [Can I add a Category Metabox to attachment?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/496/12615)
- [how can we bring category metabox to Media Library/Upload New Media Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/21726/12615)
- [Use Media Library to manage galleries like Nextgen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48747/12615)

One problem is that WordPress 3.5 made a complete revamp of the Media Management and past solutions may or may not work...